# Region code in cocoa programming

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, deprecated, macos-carbon, macos

Can anyone suggest a replacement for

`Regioncode xyz = (Regioncode)GetscriptmanagerVariable(smRegionCode)`?

The problem is that `GetscriptmanagerVariable()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionalities you're looking for is now in [CFLocale](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFLocaleRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFLocaleCreateCanonicalLanguageIdentifierFromString). Read also [Locale programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFLocales/CFLocales.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000181i) and [Internationalization programming topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i).

But you need to accept the fact that these routines don't return `RegionCode` anymore. Rather, they give you data structures which represent the user's region etc. which can be used with Core Foundation / Cocoa.

In general, it's not a good idea to replace these Carbon deprecations function by function and line by line. It's better to rewrite the affected codes wholesale to Cocoa. In particular, there's very few place where you need to use `RegionCode` explicitly; in a modern Cocoa app all these things are taken care of transparently  by the system.

Comment: I used CFLocaleGetIdentifier , it returns a canonical value with country code and language code to me , but the region code i get is verUS(0), can i relate smthn here ?

Comment: Moreover , this region code is to be used again by GetTextThemeEncoding api , which outputs several other paramaters

Comment: What kind of code do you maintain? It's a long way to go if you change those lines of code one by one.

Comment: that depends further on getTextThemeEncoding.. is there any replacement for this api that doesnot use region code

Comment: Why don't you rewrite your question accordingly? You should write the big picture (i.e. what you really want to do as the whole)... not just how one line can be saved from deprecation.